# Can I not use the pronoun “You” in the instructions?

Tags: pronouns

When I write about the need to do something, the my translator translates:

> First YOU need to perform the following steps.

But I do not appeal to a specific person, but I speak of necessity in general. Why is the pronoun 'YOU' used here, and is it possible to remove it and write how?:

> First, need to perform the following steps.

or should I write?:

> First, it is necessary to perform the following steps.

What is the best way to write instructions when I do not address a particular person?

Thanks in advance for any answer/comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to use *you* when writing advice. instructions etc. in a fairly informal tone, as though you (the writer) are addressing the reader personally.

Your second version doesn't work. The third one is fine, but its tone is more formal.

Another way would be to say *The following steps should be performed.*

Comment: Thank You so much for the explanation!